# PHP: Functionally obtaining array of properties from object

Tags: php, functional-programming, php-7

I have a simple class like this:

```
class MyClass {

    public $color = 'red';
    public $width = 200;
    public $height = 100;

    public function getValues(array $properties) {
        return array_map(function($property) {
            return $this->$property;
        }, $properties);
    }

}
```

I would like to do the following:

```
$values = (new MyClass)->getValues(['width', 'height']);
```

Where `$values` would end up containing this array: `[200, 100]`.

The following example above works perfectly fine, so my question is:
*How can we simplify the `getValues()` method?* Surely there is a simpler way to achieve this?

Requirements:

- It should be functional (no for/while loops). <- this criteria is met in my example
- It should not use a callback function. <- this criteria is *not* met in my example

Comment: How dou you deal with `$myClass->getValues(['width', 'height', 'shoesize']);`?

Comment: That's outside the scope of this problem (i.e. it should never happen). I would consider that an invalid input and allow it to fail with an exception.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you not want to use a callback? The code in your question looks like a perfectly sensible way to achieve this. You've even tagged the question as functional-programming.

Comment: @iainn Looking for ways to optimize it while still retaining the functional approach (anonymous functions are relatively heavy in PHP).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store your class-variables in an array and then use [array_intersect_key()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-intersect-key.php) and [array_flip()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-flip.php) to achieve that. Here is an example.

```
class MyClass {

    public $values = [
        'color'  => 'red',
        'width'  => '200',
        'heigth' => '100'
    ];

    public function getValues (array $properties) {
        return array_intersect_key ($this -> values, array_flip ($properties));
    }

    //EDIT 2

    public function set_value ($key, $value) {
        $this -> values[$key] = $value;
    } 

}
```

//EDIT (thanks to [mae](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1132363/mae))

It is also possible to generate an array of the class properties with [ReflectionClass()](http://php.net/manual/de/class.reflectionclass.php) and [getProperties()](http://php.net/manual/de/reflectionclass.getproperties.php).

//EDIT (thanks to [Nigel Ren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1213708/nigel-ren))

Instead of Reflection it is possible to use [get_object_vars()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.get-object-vars.php) to achieve the same output.

```
class MyClass {

    public $color  = 'red';
    public $width  = '200';
    public $heigth = '100';

    public function getValues (array $properties) {
        return array_intersect_key (get_object_vars ($this), array_flip ($properties));
    }

}
```

Comment: This is probably as good as it'll get. Might even be possible to get an array of class properties through Reflection rather than actually storing them in an array.

Comment: @mae You are right, that should also be possible. Thanks i will update my answer with that alternative approach.

Comment: This does simplify the `getValues()` part, but how does setting a value work now?  Surely that becomes a more complex operation.

Comment: Reflection is quite a heavy hit on the system, this does a lot of processing to get all of the information you need.

Comment: @NigelRen Setting is not an issue, but you are right about Reflection being very heavy. If anyone comes up with an answer like this one which does not rely on Reflection I'll accept that one, but I doubt it will be possible.

Comment: @NigelRen I edited my answer to show you how to set values.

Comment: Try replacing the reflection way of getting the values with `get_object_vars($this)`

Comment: @NigelRen Brilliant!

Answer (score -1):

Consider a new approach:

```
class MyClass
{
    public $prop = array();

    public function set($key, $value)
    {
        $this->prop[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function get($key)
    {
        return $this->prop[$key];
    }
}

$o = new MyClass();

$o->set('color', 'blue');
$o->set('pi', 3.14);

$o->get('color'); // blue
$o->get('pi'); // 3.14
```